# Why Jetpack is missing the "Feedbacks" menu item?

Tags: admin, plugin-jetpack

Is there a known issue that would prevent the "Feedbacks" menu item from showing? I have two wordpress installs, one has the menu item the other doesn't. They both have the same plugins, theme, and scripts.

Comment: is Contact Form activated?

Comment: turned out that's what it was. would you mind submitting that as an answer so I can mark it as such giving you the credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Feedbacks` admin menu with the **Jetpack** plugin installed

[image]

one has to make sure the `Contact Form` is activated through the **Jetpack** setup page `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack`:

[image]

Comment: I noticed jetpack wasn't connected (by the client) once I connected it the "activate" button popped up and solved the issue.